# if $d$ is divisible by a prime number $p$, $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then the equation $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ has no solution in integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, pell-type-equations

Show that if $d$ is divisible by a prime number $p$, $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then the equation $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ has no solution in integers.

I cant do this problem, but I have done a similar type of problem:

Prove that  $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ has no solution if $d \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Can we use it to do the above one?

Comment: What does the solvability of $x^2 - dy^2 = -1$ say about $\bigl(\frac{-1}{p}\bigr)$ when $p\mid d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has an integer solution, $(n,m)$ and $d=pk$ then

> $$-1=n^2-dm^2=n^2-p(km^2)\equiv n^2\mod p$$

but since $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ this is impossible, so no such solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite equation as  $x^2 + 1 = dy^2$

We know that the sum of 2 relatively prime squares has only prime factors $\equiv 1$ (mod 4) or = 2

if $d\equiv 3$ (mod 4) it does not have all prime factors $\equiv 1$ (mod 4) or 2

and $x^2 + 1 \;\;\;$would not have all prime factors $\equiv 1$ (mod 4) or 2

Since x and 1 are relatively prime, that is not possible.

Therefore no integer solution exists.